# How to pivot table without joining itself multiple times

Tags: postgresql, join, pivot

I have a table `ctrlr_err_hist` that has the following columns:

```
visit_id
err_cd
err_name
m1_err_cnt
m2_err_cnt
```

The possible values for `err_cd` are 0, 1, 3.

Now I want to write a query to have different errors with same `visit_id` on the same row. For example if the table has following records:

```
visit_id    err_cd    err_name    m1_err_cnt
    1         0       encoder        500
    1         3       breakout       212
    2         1       obclose         45
    2         3       breakout       143
```

This table will be joined with a `tchn_visit_hist` table on `visit_id`. If there is no data for any of the err_cd, it will be null. The end result would look like this:

```
visit_id    encoder_cnt     breakout_cnt   obclose_cnt
    1         500              212           null
    2         null             143            45
```

I wrote the following query which joins same table three times

```
select t.visit_id, t.door_id, enc.encoder_cnt, brk.breakout_cnt, ob.ob_close_cnt
from tchn_visit_hist t
left join (
    select m1_err_cnt as encoder_cnt, visit_id
    from ctrlr_err_hist  
    where err_cd = '0' 
) as enc 
on t.visit_id = enc.visit_id
left join (
    select m1_err_cnt as breakout_cnt, visit_id
    from ctrlr_err_hist  
    where err_cd = '3'
) as brk 
on t.visit_id = brk.visit_id
left join (
    select m1_err_cnt as ob_close_cnt, visit_id
    from ctrlr_err_hist  
    where err_cd = '1'
) as ob 
on t.visit_id = ob.visit_id
```

I wonder if there is a better, more efficient way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e8a9a203664260df7874fe989ef81a2f)

A simple pivot can be achieved by this way:

```
SELECT
    visit_id,
    MIN(m1_err_cnt) FILTER (WHERE err_cd = 0) as encoder_cnt,
    MIN(m1_err_cnt) FILTER (WHERE err_cd = 1) as ob_close_cnt,
    MIN(m1_err_cnt) FILTER (WHERE err_cd = 3) as breakout_cnt
FROM
    ctrlr_err_hist
GROUP BY visit_id
```

Grouping by `visit_id` and aggregating the columns your are interested in. The `FILTER` clause filters the element that should be aggregated. In this case the aggregation is only for one special `err_cd`.

Notice that you have to use an aggregation function. This is because theoretical you could have two or more rows with `(visit_id = 1, err_cd = 0)`. In that case you have to decide what you want to do with several values (`SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, whatever). Because your example contains distinct rows it doesn't matter.

After that you simply join against your `tchn_visit_hist` table:

```
SELECT t.visit_id, t.door_id, c.encoder_cnt, c.breakout_cnt, c.ob_close_cnt
FROM (
   SELECT
       visit_id,
       MIN(m1_err_cnt) FILTER (WHERE err_cd = 0) as encoder_cnt,
       MIN(m1_err_cnt) FILTER (WHERE err_cd = 1) as ob_close_cnt,
       MIN(m1_err_cnt) FILTER (WHERE err_cd = 3) as breakout_cnt
   FROM
       ctrlr_err_hist
   GROUP BY visit_id
) c
JOIN tchn_visit_hist t
ON (t.visit_id = c.visit_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make Condition in `Join`

```
select 
  a.visit_id, 
  max(b.encoder_cnt) as encoder_cnt, 
  max(b.breakout_cnt) as breakout_cnt, 
  max(b.ob_close_cnt) as ob_close_cnt
from 
  tchn_visit_hist a
  left join(select 
              case when err_cd = '0' then m1_err_cnt end as encoder_cnt, 
              case when err_cd = '3' then m1_err_cnt end as breakout_cnt,
              case when err_cd = '1' then m1_err_cnt end as ob_close_cnt,
              case when err_cd = '0' then visit_id end as encoder_visit, 
              case when err_cd = '3' then visit_id end as breakout_visit,
              case when err_cd = '1' then visit_id end as ob_close_visit
            from
              tchn_visit_hist) b on case 
                                      when a.err_cd = '0' then a.visit_id = encoder_visit
                                      when a.err_cd = '3' then a.visit_id = breakout_visit
                                      when a.err_cd = '1' then a.visit_id = ob_close_visit
                                     end
group by
   a.visit_id
order by
   a.visit_id asc
```

Here the [**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=318b85a67147d0c34ceb09c22c5213e4)